# Can't a chm file be opened on network-drive?

Tags: windows, samba, smb, chm

I have a [chm](http://filext.com/file-extension/CHM) file. The file opens well on my local machine.
But on network-drive connected SMB or SAMBA, it doesn't work. Why?

It just shows "Navigation to the webpage was canceled" in right pane.

Comment: What happens when you open it from a network drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click the file and open its properties. Make sure that it's not blocked or marked as untrusted.